# SplashScreen IOException

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, splash-screen

```
SplashScreen s = new SplashScreen(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),"splash.png");
s.Show(false);
```

when invoking `s.Show()` whether the parameter is `false` or `true`, it throws an `IOException`
with the message

> Cannot locate resource 'splash.png'

even though that splash.png is added to resources and its **Build Action** is **Resource**.

I have noticed many problems when using images in WPF, also with `Image` control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the principle "My Code doesn't work and I don't know why. My code Works and I don't know why", I have solved the problem.

First I have made the **Build Action** of the splash image as **Resource**. (Putting the image as **Embedded Resource** didn't solved the problem).

Second, My code is :

```
SplashScreen s = new SplashScreen("resources/splash.png");
s.Show(false);
/* do some things */
s.Close(Timespan.FromMilliseconds(300));
```

Answer (score 1):

> even though that splash.png is added to resources and its Build Action is Resource.

Wrong build action, make it `Embedded Resource`.  If you still have trouble then use ildasm.exe to look at the assembly manifest for the .mresource directive to ensure that the resource got properly embedded with the expected name.

Or use a file, following these [how-to steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Generally the more sane approach since it doesn't make that much sense to have a large resource occupy address space for the life of the program when it is only needed for a short amount of time at the start of the program.

Comment: `.mresource public JPad.Resources.splash.png
{
  // Offset: 0x000041E0 Length: 0x000024B7
  // WARNING: managed resource file JPad.Resources.splash.png created
}`
I changed it to `Embedded Resource`, exception is still handled.

Comment: I had tried it using a file, and it works well but I need to pass `false` to `SplashScreen.Show`

Comment: "JPad.Resources" is very odd, a more common name would be "WpfApplication1.splash.png".  In other words, it normally prefixes the default namespace name as set in the Project + Properties, Application tab.  No idea what you are doing but a random guess would be to use "Resources.splash.png" if the default namespace is "JPad".  If you created a resource-only assembly then Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try with explicitly specifying the assembly name, even though the caller was in the same assembly as the resource.

Here's how it looks with a Pack URI syntax:

```
pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/MyResourcesFolder/MyImage.png
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx